# Uploading big files with POST freezes the system

Tags: macos, qt, file-upload, qnetworkaccessmanager

i have an application which upload files (video files) to a server using the standard post request, something like:

```
QNetworkRequest  request(QUrl("myUrl"));
QString bound="margin";
QByteArray data(QString("--"+bound+"\r\n").toLatin1());

data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media_id\"\r\n\r\n";
data += id + "\r\n";
data += QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toLatin1();

QString str = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + name + "\r\n";
data += str;
data += "Content-Type: video/mp4\r\n\r\n";

QFile f(path);
if(! f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    qDebug() << "uploadMediaRequest error opening " << path;
    return false;
}


QByteArray bytes;
bytes = f.readAll();

data.append(bytes);
data += "\r\n";
data += QString("--" + bound + "\r\n.").toLatin1();
data += "\r\n";

f.close();

request.setRawHeader(QString("Accept").toLatin1(),QString("application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01").toLatin1());
request.setRawHeader(QString("Origin").toLatin1(),QString("http://dev.teamhood.io").toLatin1());
request.setRawHeader(QString("API-Client").toLatin1(),QString("desktop").toLatin1());
request.setRawHeader(QString("withCredentials").toLatin1(), QString("true").toLatin1());
request.setRawHeader(QString("Content-Type").toLatin1(),QString("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + bound).toLatin1());
request.setRawHeader(QString("Content-Length").toLatin1(), QString::number(data.length()).toLatin1());
```

And then POST that request.
For files of 1GB or less it works just fine but if i try to upload a file of 1,5GB i get

```
myProgramName[948:32028] Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x7fff7c37bb60> { count = 1, contents =
"XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff7c37bfa8> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }}>
Got xpc error message: Connection interrupted
```

and the app and the SO freeze to death.
I suppose i can split the big files and upload them in parts and make the server assemble them but i was wondering if any of you could give me an explanation for this strange errors.

I work with OSX & Qt 5.4, thx in advance!

Comment: Reading 1.5 GB of data into a single array is not the best idea. You should use `QNetworkAccessManager::post(const QNetworkRequest & request, QHttpMultiPart * multiPart)`, as `QHttpMultiPart` allows adding files for upload via `QHttpPart::setBodyDevice`. In this scenario, the file will be read internally by Qt in small chunks.

Comment: Ty for your help. I changed the post call including                     `QHttpMultiPart * multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
    multiPart->setBoundary(data);` and while its better practice the errors stand still

Comment: I don't understand what you did. First, `setBoundary` is used to change boundary string used to separate parts of multipart data. You're not supposed to change it at all, let alone put your data in it. Second, if you still have `data` variable as it was, you still read all your file in memory, which is unacceptable. Try to remove file reading completely and use `QHttpMultiPart` and `QHttpPart` abilities to put your file contents into the request.

Comment: You were right in everything! Its solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by user Pavel Strakhov:

```
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("myUrl"));

QFile *f = new QFile(path);
if(! f->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    qDebug() << "uploadMediaRequest error opening " << path;
    return false;
}

QHttpMultiPart * multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
QHttpPart idPart, mediaPart;
idPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,QVariant("form-data; name=\"media_id\""));
idPart.setBody(id.toLatin1());

mediaPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, type); 
mediaPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""+ name + "\""));
mediaPart.setBodyDevice(f);
f->setParent(multiPart); 

multiPart->append(idPart);
multiPart->append(mediaPart);

request.setRawHeader(QString("Accept").toLatin1(),QString("application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01").toLatin1());
request.setRawHeader(QString("Origin").toLatin1(),QString("http://dev.teamhood.io").toLatin1());
request.setRawHeader(QString("API-Client").toLatin1(),QString("desktop").toLatin1());
request.setRawHeader(QString("withCredentials").toLatin1(), QString("true").toLatin1());

networkManager->post(request, multiPart));
```

Now it runs great.