# Sending files via QHttpMultiPart freezes

Tags: c++, qt, http, qt5, multipart

I am trying to send "big" files (~100MB) to my RestAPI, but I am running into problems with QHttpMultiPart.

The code that I am using to send the local file from the client to the server is pretty straight forward:

```
   // Create multi-part
   QHttpMultiPart* multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);


   // Open file
   QFile* file = new QFile(myFilePath);
   file->setParent(multiPart);
   // -- snip: Check if opening the file was success full --


   // Create file part
   QHttpPart filePart;
   filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
                      QVariant("multipart/form-data"));
   filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,
                      QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" +
                               file->fileName() + "\""));
   filePart.setBodyDevice(file);   // <--- Set the file as body device


   // Add file part
   multiPart->append(filePart);


   // Setup request
   QNetworkRequest testRequest { myApiUrl };
   testRequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
                         "multipart/form-data");
   testRequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,
                         QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" +
                                  myFileName + "\""));

   // -- snip: Some SSL configuration --

   // Send request
   auto reply = m_networkAccessManager.post(testRequest, multiPart);
   m_testReply.reset(reply);
```

The above code works just fine for very small files (.txt files with some words as content), but fails if the files get bigger (e.g. pdf file with 202KB).
I have seen this stackoverflow conversation: [Uploading big files with POST freezes the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713978/uploading-big-files-with-post-freezes-the-system) (See the solution) and from what I see, I am doing nothing really different but my application still freezes.

My RestAPI is expecting a stream of type "multipart/...", it receives and processes the small file just fine. For bigger files instead, it blocks while waiting for the chunk to arrive and never continues.

I have connected some slots to the signals of `QNetworkReply` to get notifications on the progress of my request:

```
    connect(m_testReply.get(), &QNetworkReply::uploadProgress,
            [](qint64 bytesSent, qint64 bytesTotal)
            {
                qDebug() << QString::number(bytesSent) + " of " +
                                QString::number(bytesTotal) + " uploaded";
            });

    connect(m_testReply.get(), &QNetworkReply::finished,
            []()
            {
                qDebug() << "Upload finished!";
            });
```

It seems to always stop after the first chunk was sent, so my output is: `"16381" of "201324" uploaded`. I suspect that the upload for small files succeeds, just because there only is one chunk to upload.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.

I have called: `file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)` while the file I am reading is not Text, opening the file simply via: `file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)` fixed it.